# Assigning a Validation Group to the autogenerated Insert button in an ASP.Net Details View

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Is there a way to add a ValidationGroup to autogenerated DetailsView buttons in ASP.Net?

Or do I have to set autogenerate=false and make my own?

Comment: http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/496911-input-validation-detailsview

Comment: @TimSchmelter I had just read that before posting this question, but the answer seemed vague. I read up on CommandNames but I didn't understand how they factored into it?

Comment: Oh, I just realized what he meant by well-known command names.

Answer (score 0):

While messing around with the CommandNames property, I stumbled upon an easy way to add a validation group to a button, while still enjoying most of the benefits of the autogenerated features.

Its as easy as setting CommandName = "Insert". From what I can tell, the automatically generated EventHandler that eventually handles the bubbleevent raised by the button checks for CommandName = "Insert", "Update", etc.

If you know the name of the Command that the Event Handler is going to look for, you can simply set your button's CommandName = to that Command and it will handle it for you.

You still have to make your own button, but you don't have to rewrite the event handler and you can set a validation group to your button.